# Django DB Routers

Tags: django, router

My django application will connect with 3 diffrent databases (SQLite as default, PostgreSQLfor product and manufacturer database, MSSQL for Funds database) for 3 different apps (product, manufacturer, funds)

I have created 3 routers in `routers.py` (`productdbrouter`, `manufacturerdbrouter`, `fundsdbrouter`) file in each app to perform the read, write operations depending on the app_lable name.

On my project settings file I have created a `DATABASE_ROUTERS` configuration as:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    "product.routers.productdbrouter","manufacturer.routers.manufacturerdbrouter", "funds.routers.fundsdbrouter",
]
```

Now when I try to access the applications it always tries to find the table from the first router in the database configuration(`product.routers.productdbrouter` in this case) and if the table is missing then it tries to fetches from the default router (SQLite). 
what I expect is the router to map to the products/manufacturer/Funds database depending on the model I am trying to fetch.

Highly appriciate the suggestion on what Iam missing on the configuration?

By the way iam using Django=2.2.4

Code

products\router.py

```
class productdbrouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):    
        if model._meta.app_label== 'product':
            return 'productdb'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return 'productdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'product' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label=='product':
            return db=='productdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'productdb' or model._meta.app_label == "product":
            return False  # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
        else:  # but all other models/databases are fine
            return True
```

manufacturer\router.py

```
class manufacturerdbrouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):    
        if model._meta.app_label== 'manufacturer':
            return 'manufacturerdb'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'manufacturer':
            return 'manufacturerdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'manufacturer' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'manufacturer':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label=='manufacturer':
            return db=='manufacturerdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'manufacturerdb' or model._meta.app_label == "manufacturer":
            return False  # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
        else:  # but all other models/databases are fine
            return True
```

funds\router.py

```
class fundsdbrouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):    
        if model._meta.app_label== 'funds':
            return 'fundsdb'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'funds':
            return 'fundsdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'funds' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'funds':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label=='funds':
            return db=='fundsdb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'fundsdb' or model._meta.app_label == "funds":
            return False  # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
        else:  # but all other models/databases are fine
            return True
```

Note: I have made allow_syncdb =false as I am not pushing any values from the django application. All the changes made in the application will be through other application.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include the code for the three `routers.py` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're returning a suggestion with the code `return 'default'` instead of using `return None`. See the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

You can also probably get away with using a single router across your entire project, something like this:

```
class MyRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return 'productdb'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'manufacturer':
            return 'manufacturerdb'

        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return 'productdb'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'manufacturer':
            return 'manufacturerdb'

        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db in (
                'productdb',
                'manufacturerdb',
        ):
            return False

        return True
```

What we're doing is routing reads and writes for each Django app you have created to the appropriate database (as defined in `DATABASES` in Django's settings), or returning `None`, which will use the default SQLite database in your setup. We're also telling Django not to create any migrations against PostgreSQL or MSSQL, since I'm guessing you won't want to have Django handle the structure of those databases.

However, we are not accounting for `allow_relation` here; it will be up to to you not to set any relations across database boundaries. For example, you couldn't set up a `ForeignKey` from SQLite to PostgreSQL. Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Nice idea. will try this.Any reason why the multiple routers are not working?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're doing `return 'default'` instead of `return None` in your routers. IIRC, when you explicitly return a database instance, it won't continue through the rest of your routers. Can you try changing `return 'default'` to `return None` in all three of your `routers.py` files?

Comment: I've amended my answer with a link to the docs which says to use `return None`.

Comment: Hi,Yes the default database was set in the routers, I have modified the code with the single router instead of multiple routers and I can able to achive the result with the single router. Thanks for the help